# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-lab

An error occurred when I ran the following command：

```
docker run --rm --name tf-notebook -v /home/ubt16/jpyws:/dockerDir -p 9876:8888 lab:v1 jupyter lab --allow-root
```

my description：

/home/ubt16/jpyws is mounted to /dockerDir, and I have a chinese-named folder under the /home/ubt16/jpyws directory.
When I jump to the web link of jupyter lab, the file named in Chinese cannot be displayed and an error is reported,but English-named folders can be displayed successfully.

error：

```
[W 03:18:17.131 LabApp] failed to decode filename 'AI鍏ラ棬璇剧▼鈥旂涓€鑺傝': 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
[W 03:18:17.135 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
```

Comment: Can you provide which python script is running as container startup?
CMD or ENTRYPOINT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)